# Error casting FieldExpression to LambdaExpression using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, lambda, linqkit

I'm getting the error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'` when running the below code.

The intent of this code is to allow me to filter records (Entity Framework Code First / Linq to SQL) for those containing certain strings.

NB: I'm using the third party library LinqKit: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

```
FilterHelper<Country> helper = new FilterHelper<Country>();
helper.AddContains(searchAlpha2, c => c.Alpha2);
helper.AddContains(searchAlpha3, c => c.Alpha3);
helper.AddContains(searchName, c => c.Name);

IQueryable<Country> countries = db.Countries.AsExpandable().Where(helper.Predicate);
```

...

```
public class FilterHelper<T>
{
    public delegate string GetColumn<T>(T item);

    private Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate; 

    public FilterHelper()
    {
        this.predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
    }
    public void AddContains(string searchText, GetColumn<T> getColumn)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText))
            predicate = predicate.And(c => getColumn(c) != null ? getColumn(c).Contains(searchText) : false);
    }  
    public Expression<Func<T,bool>> Predicate
    {
        get { return this.predicate; }
    }

}
```

Any suggestions on how I could rewrite this to avoid the above error?

NB: code also on CodeReview as my original question related to refactoring.  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54888/refactor-c-linq-code-to-reduce-duplication

Comment: Are you using the DLL from the site you linked to, or from NuGet?  I think this is something that has been fixed, so try the NuGet version if you aren't already.

Comment: Thanks Mark; I was using the one from the site; replacing with NuGet version now...

Comment: Sadly still getting the same (v1.1.1 from nuget / related page: https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/)

Comment: Same error, different cause then.  I suspect that it's related to the getColumn parameter, which seems like it should be something like `Expression<Func<T, string>>` so that the predicate can use the property, instead of the value, but I'm just starting to learn about expressions and can't be much help there.

Comment: @JohnLBevan Can you provide an example of how you resolved your issue using Gordon's answer? As hard as I try, I can't seem to make a type of `Expression<Func<U,T>>` work in place of your `getColumn<T>` delegate.

Comment: I think I got it! Looks like I needed to use Invoke. So if `getColumn` is of type `Expression<Func<T, string>>`, then `predicate = predicate.And(c => getColumn.Invoke(c) != null ? ...);`

Comment: Nice one @karol; thanks for sharing; I was trying to recall what code I'd used this in to dig out an answer for you, but you beat me to it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A FieldExpression is not a LambdaExpression. You can make one as the body of an expression. In the debugger you can try the following to explore the structure of a LambdaExpression:

```
Expression<Func<U,T>> f = t => t.FieldName;
```

then in the debugger, look at f, which is of type LambdaExpression, and the Body of LambdaExpression which is Field Expression.